# Meaning of the covariance matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, multivariate-distribution

I wonder about the excessive usage of the covariance matrix across all kinds of machine learning tools. So far, for me, the covariance is just a pre-step to get to the correlation. And as there is an obvious reason for the correlation itself, I wonder why I encounter the covariance so often. And, however, I wonder in general why it is used so much. What is/are the purposes for the covariance matrix?

Comment: why "there is an obvious reason for the correlation itself" ?

Comment: The correlation has a purpose?

Comment: I don't understand - you are saying your question " there is an obvious reason for the correlation itself," - I wonder what differences between correlation and covariance makes it difficult ?

Comment: It is meant like: Is the correlation the only purpose for a covariance (matrix)? Or are there further purposes of the covariance (matrix)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is essential when u look at theory of linear models, matrix algebra and also u can see usefulness in Methods of multivariate analysis book (because in ML u do use more than 1 variables variables so is explained in details theory behind that).

**In simple words:** covariance matrix show the  `distribution magnitude and measure of directional`[relationship between variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) `for multivariate data in multidimensional space` and useful tool for `decorrelate variables or applied as transformation for other variables`. Here is math-info cor and cov [cor vs cov in ML space](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/covariance-vs-correlation.html)

Also, is very useful for models and special for big data modeling, dimension reductions aka PCA and family. I use it for feature reduction too and there u can use from cov matrix or corr matrix to extract requirements and build PCs and more (this is a-lot to explain here and also is part of  explaining PCA).

Hope it helps and can add math explanation if is the case.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so I guess the most important purpose then is probably to estimate the dimensions of the distribution. I think this is also done in PCA as you use the largest eigenvalues.